# Protect Keycloak instance and Custom Protocol Mappers on production environment

Tags: security, keycloak

In my scenario:

1. Keycloak and my own on-premise client application are installed together on my customer's infrastructure.
2. Keycloak includes a Custom Protocol Mapper written by me that injects the appropriate authentication claims into the access token (there is additional logic to estimate which claims should be added)
3. my client can provide its own 3rd party application that logs in using this Keycloak instance and uses the access tokens to access my on-premise application API that verifies these claims to estimate my clients permissions.

Question:
Is there a way to make sure, from the point of view of my client application, that the Custom Protocol Mapper on the Keycloak side has not been modified/hacked/replaced by something else and its new version does not inject into access token always maximum permissions?

I'm wondering if there isn't some way to, for example, digitally sign the keycloak files and put some data in the access token so that the client application can verify the integrity of the Custom Protocol Mapper.